# What is the "^=" operator?

Tags: solidity

I found this weird gist online for generating random numbers. Please remember that, despite the code's comments, generating random numbers on-chain is insecure for values more than 2.5 ETH.

```
// this labyrinth contract as a public utility can be used as an "entropy crawler", 
// using the state itself as a source of entropy (generated entirely from human social coordination 
// that is highly random. )

contract Labyrinth {

  uint entropy;

  function getRandomNumber() public returns (uint) {
    entropy ^= uint(blockhash(entropy % block.number));
    return entropy;
  }

}
```

What is the "^=" operator and what does it do? I tried searching in javascript, solidity, and other languages through Google but nothing is coming up.

Source: https://gist.github.com/resilience-me/8e877bc39a9f8d86f17f08bc62d71d70

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is perhaps more of a general programming question than anything specific to Solidity...

It's a bitwise exclusive OR ([XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) - `^`), combined with an assignment operator (`=`).

`a ^= b` is equivalent to `a = a ^ b`, in a similar way to `a = a + 1` being written `a += 1`.

Comment: Thanks. Yea I figured it was that, but then in the context of the rest of the function... ...  blockhash is supposed to accept inputs from 0 to 256, right?... I guess I am just wondering how the above function works, if entropy is a really big number, divided by block.number ( another really big number) , there's no guarantee the modulo will be less than 256? or is there? i guess the above contract doesn't even work? (it looks like it should though by everything i've been reading of this guy)

Comment: FYI, I asked that comment as a question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67786/how-does-this-4-line-labyrinth-contract-work

Comment: Sorry for missing your follow-up comment. Agree with your and Rob's assertions in the other question :-)