# How does this 4-line labyrinth contract work?

Tags: solidity, randomness

```
contract Labyrinth {

  uint entropy;

  function getRandomNumber() public returns (uint) {
    entropy ^= uint(blockhash(entropy % block.number));
    return entropy;
  }

}
```

I found this weird gist online for generating random numbers. Please remember that, despite the code's comments (which i just removed), generating random numbers on-chain is insecure for values more than 2.5 ETH.

The `blockhash` function is supposed to accept inputs from 0 to 256, right...  I guess I am just wondering how the above function works, if entropy is a really big number, divided by block.number (another really big number), There's no guarantee the modulo will be less than 256? or is there?

Here's another question i just asked on this: [What is the "^=" operator?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67783/what-is-the-operator/67784#67784) . I did assume that's what the `^=` operator did, but figured I must be misunderstanding it because the rest of the contract doesn't make sense.

Here's the contract source: https://gist.github.com/resilience-me/69d605844973df694c613ba71439a6fa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it works at all, for multiple reasons.

It's using past information, so not only not random. It's also easy to compute in advance. I fiddled around a little so at least it picks a block that will probably have an interesting hash.

```
contract Labyrinth {

  // WARN
  // UNSAFE: DO NOT USE

  uint entropy;

  function getRandomishNumber() public returns (uint) {
    uint offset = entropy % 255 + 1; // let's go back at least one block for Remix
    uint blockNumber = block.number - offset;
    entropy ^= uint(blockhash(blockNumber));
    return entropy;
  }

}
```

Hope it helps.